# Can a User in Domain A be a member of a Group in Domain B?

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group, directorysearcher

Via the Directory Searcher in C# we want to get information about a user from the Active Directory in Windows. We want to know all the groups of a specific user:

```
var lDomain = "DomainA";
var lSamAccountName = "MyUserName";

var lDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + lDomain);

using (DirectorySearcher lDirectorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", lSamAccountName)))
{
    lDirectorySearcher.SearchRoot = lDirectoryEntry;
    lDirectorySearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    lDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");

    [...]
}
```

**Question 1:** Is it possible, that a User in Domain A is a member of a group that is defined in Domain B?

**Question 2:** Is it possible, that a User in Fores A is a member of a group that is defined in Forest B?

Comment: Yes. I'm at work right now and we have about 12 domains in the forest, and I'm a member of groups on at least 2 other domains.  Get a DirectorySearcher from the Forest object and you'll be able to find instances across domains. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333823/search-entire-active-directory-forest-by-username

Comment: Thank you very much. Now a second question: Is it possible, that a User A in Forest A is a member of a Group in trusted Forest B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a user can be a Member from a Group in a different domain. This is defined by the scope the group has.

1. Universal

Users from any domain in the same forest (collection of domains) can be in this group.

2. Global

Only Users from the same domain are allowed

3. Domain local

Only Users from the any domain or any trusted domain are allowed (This includes other forests altogether).

For further reading go [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579255(v=ws.11).aspx).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Regarding 1. Are groups Cross-Forest visible? E.g. Is it possible, that a User A in Forest A is a member of a Group in trusted Forest B?

Comment: Yes that should be possible if the group is Domain local. @Simon